# JQuery Selector code validation for list of select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm having situation like 3 select box is there in a form

```
    <form>
   <select name="select1">
 <option value="a">a</option>
 <option value="b">b</option>
 <option value="c">c</option>
 </select>

<select name="select2">
 <option value="a">a</option>
 <option value="b">b</option>
 <option value="c">c</option>
 </select>
  <select name="select3">
 <option value="a">a</option>
 <option value="b">b</option>
 <option value="c">c</option>
 </select> </form>
```

On submitting this form i have to check atleast one of the select box value should be "a".

Is there any one line selctor query like jQuery['form'].find('select val=="a"').length() like this .

Thanks,
Nithish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, and you want to know if at least one selected `option` has the value of '`a`', it should look like

```
if( $('form').find('option:selected[value=a]').length ) {
   /*  */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/Zvmfg/

```
jQuery('form select option:selected[value="a"]').length;
```

So you could do:

```
if( jQuery('form select option:selected[value="a"]').length ) {
    alert( 'at least one was selected' );
} else {
    alert( 'no "a" values selected' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `$('form#yourform option:selected[value="a"]').length > 0`